# Python socket UDP: Able to send string one way but not the other

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I am attempting a chat application using python socket module. I can send any string from my desktop computer to my laptop, but not the other way. I am using UDP and for the IP, IPV4.

client.py:

```
# Message Sender
import os
from socket import *
host = "192.168.1.14" #IP address of target computer
port = 13000
addr = (host, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
while True:
    data = input("Enter a message to send or type 'exit': ")
    UDPSock.sendto(data.encode("ascii"), addr)
    if data == "exit":
        break
UDPSock.close()
os._exit(0)
```

server.py:

```
# Message Receiver
import os
from socket import *
host = ""
port = 13000
buf = 1024
addr = (host, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.bind(addr)
print ("Waiting to receive messages...")
while True:
    (data, addr) = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
    print ("Received message: " + data.decode("ascii"))
    if data == "exit":
        break
UDPSock.close()
os._exit(0)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you mean you're running client.py from your laptop & server on your desktop => it works, and inverting the programs/computers doesn't?

Comment: Got firewall software? Could simply be that one end has a firewall rule that blocks incoming data. Make sure that port 13000 is enabled and/or python.exe is allowed to use all networks.

Comment: Port meaning a data bus. You can't send anythings if used before. Please read `socket.create_connection` documents. Internet not work with your code style. Available_port(port > 1024) to Server _Port. Computer automaticaly register your used port number, otherwise how to raised *Source is unavailable* error ?

Comment: Another point is : Create connection before binding a service. For testing port is available, a app is ghost , etc.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Yeah